# Pandas: Clean Up Data Frame by Eliminating NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with a several `NaN` values in columns. The data in" STAN-x" needs only to match the associated "Statement". And duplicate "Statement" values can be eliminated.

So I have the following data frame:

```
     Statement     STAN-A    STAN-B     STAN-C            STAN-D                      STAN-E                       STAN-F
0    Statement A   AB.AM-1   ABC ABC 1               NaN                         NaN                          NaN                         NaN
1    Statement A   AB.AM-1         NaN  ABCDE 5 ABCDE.01                         NaN                          NaN                         NaN
1    Statement A   AB.AM-1         NaN  ABCDE 5 ABCDE.02                         NaN                          NaN                         NaN
2    Statement A   AB.AM-1         NaN               NaN  ABC 62443-2-1:2009 4.2.3.4                          NaN                         NaN
3    Statement A   AB.AM-1         NaN               NaN   ABC 62443-3-3:2013 SR 7.8                          NaN                         NaN
4    Statement A   AB.AM-1         NaN               NaN                         NaN   ABC/ABC 27001:2013 A.8.1.1                         NaN
4    Statement A   AB.AM-1         NaN               NaN                         NaN                      A.8.1.2                         NaN
5    Statement A   AB.AM-1         NaN               NaN                         NaN                          NaN  ABCD AB 800-53 Rev. 4 CM-8
5    Statement A   AB.AM-1         NaN               NaN                         NaN                          NaN                        PM-5
6    Statement B   AB.AM-2   ABC ABC 2               NaN                         NaN                          NaN                         NaN
7    Statement B   AB.AM-2         NaN  ABCDE 5 ABCDE.01                         NaN                          NaN                         NaN
7    Statement B   AB.AM-2         NaN  ABCDE 5 ABCDE.02                         NaN                          NaN                         NaN
7    Statement B   AB.AM-2         NaN  ABCDE 5 ABCDE.05                         NaN                          NaN                         NaN
8    Statement B   AB.AM-2         NaN               NaN  ABC 62443-2-1:2009 4.2.3.4                          NaN                         NaN
9    Statement B   AB.AM-2         NaN               NaN   ABC 62443-3-3:2013 SR 7.8                          NaN                         NaN
10   Statement B   AB.AM-2         NaN               NaN                         NaN   ABC/ABC 27001:2013 A.8.1.1                         NAN
11   Statement B   AB.AM-2         NaN               NaN                         NaN                          NAN  ABCD AB 800-53 Rev. 5 CM-9
```

And I'm trying to turn it into this:

```
    Statement      STAN-A    STAN-B     STAN-C            STAN-D                      STAN-E                       STAN-F
0    Statement A   AB.AM-1   ABC ABC 1  ABCDE 5 ABCDE.01  ABC 62443-2-1:2009 4.2.3.4  ABC/ABC 27001:2013 A.8.1.1   ABCD AB 800-53 Rev. 4 CM-8
1    Statement A   AB.AM-1         NaN  ABCDE 5 ABCDE.02   ABC 62443-3-3:2013 SR 7.8                     A.8.1.2                         PM-5
2    Statement A   AB.AM-1         NaN               NaN  ABC 62443-2-1:2009 4.2.3.4                         NaN                         NaN
3    Statement B   AB.AM-2   ABC ABC 2  ABCDE 5 ABCDE.01  ABC 62443-2-1:2009 4.2.3.4  ABC/ABC 27001:2013 A.8.1.1   ABCD AB 800-53 Rev. 5 CM-9
4    Statement B   AB.AM-2         NaN  ABCDE 5 ABCDE.02   ABC 62443-3-3:2013 SR 7.8                         NaN                         NaN
5    Statement B   AB.AM-2         NaN  ABCDE 5 ABCDE.05                         NaN                         NaN                         NaN
```

So far I've tried `df.dropna()`, but, of course, that leaves me with no values. I've also tried the following:

```
df.assign(**{'STAN-B': df['STAN-B'].join(df['STAN-B'].dropna())})
```

But I get:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'join'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
x = df.groupby("Statement").apply(lambda x: x.apply(sorted, key=pd.isna))
x = x.dropna(subset=x.loc[:, "STAN-B":].columns, how="all")
print(x.reset_index(drop=True))
```

Prints:

```
     Statement   STAN-A     STAN-B            STAN-C                      STAN-D                      STAN-E                      STAN-F
0  Statement A  AB.AM-1  ABC ABC 1  ABCDE 5 ABCDE.01  ABC 62443-2-1:2009 4.2.3.4  ABC/ABC 27001:2013 A.8.1.1  ABCD AB 800-53 Rev. 4 CM-8
1  Statement A  AB.AM-1        NaN  ABCDE 5 ABCDE.02   ABC 62443-3-3:2013 SR 7.8                     A.8.1.2                        PM-5
2  Statement B  AB.AM-2  ABC ABC 2  ABCDE 5 ABCDE.01  ABC 62443-2-1:2009 4.2.3.4  ABC/ABC 27001:2013 A.8.1.1  ABCD AB 800-53 Rev. 5 CM-9
3  Statement B  AB.AM-2        NaN  ABCDE 5 ABCDE.02   ABC 62443-3-3:2013 SR 7.8                         NaN                         NaN
4  Statement B  AB.AM-2        NaN  ABCDE 5 ABCDE.05                         NaN                         NaN                         NaN
```

---

NOTE: If you're creating this dataframe with `pd.concat`, try to add `axis=1` as a parameter.

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much!